# Python Selenium ng-click action

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, angularjs-ng-click

I've been searching for a solution here on Stackoverflow or Google, but unfortunately I couldn't find any solution.
I'm trying to do webscrape on a website, but I can not click on a button with Python + Selenium + Chrome webdriver.

The HTML code on the website:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="launch()" title="HTTP/HTTPS: WebSQL">
<div class="flex-column-centered">
    <f-icon class="bookmark-icon-large fa-globe" ng-class="TYPE_MAP[bookmark.apptype].icon"></f-icon>
    <span class="ng-binding">WebSQL</span>
</div> </button>
```

I understand that is AngularJS and I tried CSS selector and Xpath, none of these seem to work in my case.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this xpath :

```
//span[text()='WebSQL']/../..
```

I would suggest you to have explicit wait like this :

```
WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='WebSQL']/../.."))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!
Can you explain to me, what this means "/../.." in the regular expression?

Comment: /.. means that you wanna go to parent from the current node.

Comment: That makes sense, and actually a clever way to find the button element.